# View not displaying in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I had one  existing rails application and i was asked to add a few features in this application.

So I wrote a view file,action for the new feature.

But I straight away added .html.erb file and my action in the existing file directories but now view for the new feature is not coming.

Is it because i added the files directly rather than running a command

I have also modified the route file.

Comment: Please post your code!

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between command and manual. 
Check the path and name of your new view and action.

Answer (score 0):

threes things should be done.
- add route and make sure it matches controller name and method name
- add method in the specified controller
- create view with the same name as method name or specify what you want to render using e.g. `render edit`.

Comment: One thing more....I have written the action of my view in an existing controller.Do you think this might be a problem?

Comment: What i have done is like this :-
Route File :-
match "/someurl" , to "someOldControllerName#someurl"

View file :
someurl.html.erb
-->contains some html.erb

oldContainer
added a new method someurl

What else do you think i should add?

Comment: unless you upload code for routes.rb and your controllers, it is hard to understand and help you

Comment: It's the code of my organisation so can't upload :(

Comment: but yeah my actions is 

def someName


if userIsNotInDataBase
 @ warning=some_message
end

end

Do you think it is because @ warning might be null
and this @ warning is being used in view file